# Parse Zulu time suffix in Chrono - which format?

Tags: datetime, rust, rust-chrono

The following runs fine:

```rust
use chrono::{DateTime};


fn main() {
    let parse_from_str = DateTime::parse_from_str;
    let ts = "2000-01-01T01:23+01:00";
    let fmt = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%z";
    let parsed = parse_from_str(ts, fmt);
    println!("{:?}", parsed);
}
```

runs fine and returns

```
Ok(2000-01-01T01:23:00+01:00)
```

However, if I instead put

```rust
let ts = "2000-01-01T01:23Z";
```

then it fails:

```
Err(ParseError(Invalid))
```

By contrast, in Python, I can parse that string using this format:

```py
In [1]: import datetime as dt

In [2]: dt.datetime.strptime("2000-01-01T01:23Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%z")
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 1, 23, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Which one is right?

NOTE: I'm aware that I could get this one to parse using `let fmt = "%+";`. I'm just asking if there's a way to parse it by specifying the full format string explicitly

Comment: why not use `DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339` --> [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d08584c0eedd3dc22dea74dda0238b9c)

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'm asking if there's a way to parse it by specifying the full format string explicitly

Comment: I've edited the question so that `parse_from_rfc3339 ` won't work

Comment: I just wanted to point that out as an *option*. You don't have to come up with some strange input; I still think this is a good question.

Comment: why not create an issue on github ?